# booster responsive navbar button can't click yii

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am having the exact same problem as the one they show on their site.
If you check it on the website, it's also not working. 
I don't seem to quite understand what's the problem. Can't click on any of the dropdowns.

[Link to it](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/widgets/navigation/view/navbar.html#description) and scroll down to Responsive navbar->dropdown

```
<?php $this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',
    array(
        'type' => null,
        'brand' => '<img src="'.$baseurl.'/images/site/logo.png"/>',
        'brandUrl' => 'index.php',
        'collapse' => true, 
        'fixed' => false,
        'id'=>'loggedin-header',
        'items' => array(
                array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
            'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'pull-right'),
                'items' => array(
                    array(
                    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                    'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'pull-right'),
                    'icon'=> 'user',
                    'label'=> 'Hello ' .$name,
                    'encodeLabel'=>true,
                    'items'=>array(
                        array('icon'=>'user','label'=>"Profile", 'url'=>array('/user/profile/view','id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId()), ),
                array('icon'=>'gift','label'=>' Rewards', 'url'=>array('/user/rewards/view','id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId())),
                array('icon'=>'cogs','label'=>' Settings', 'url'=>array('/user/profile/update','id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId())),
                        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('icon'=>'sign-out','label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                    ),
                    ),              
            ),
                ),

),                  
  ));
  ?>
```

Comment: In the example the links all have hash (#) links. Are you sure you have correct links placed?

Comment: well the cursor doesn't show... even if used cursor: pointer. It just can't be clicked. Try adding a link. I'm pretty sure what i have are correct links, because it works fine when it's not in responsive.

Comment: show your code of TbNavbar.

Comment: i updated.. try going to the main page booster... and their navbar on responsive.. can't click on it. http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/